# How to get images with URL link into a local directory as another column in the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, wget, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I've used tweepy to collect twitter users' info including their public image and that shows up as an url (the img_path column), just wondering how can I get an local path for the image and shows up as another column in my dataframe?

```
description id  lang    name    screen_name img_path
0   Husband, Father to a son ,COOL MF in General U...   997270922976481282  en  Bishop Sycamore Starting CB JEFF_SON_334    https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/158057944...
1   BBBholic    69133413    en  Tarsis  tarsismenezes   https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/128051304...
2   This life is 100% your responsibility, so know...   508551405   en      My_business_man https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/152447712...
```

I have tried using wget to download the images in a separate folder and that worked, but not sure how can I match the downloaded image in local path to the dataframe?

Comment: What are the names of the image files?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.